# Module zip is not available on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Getting error `zip: command not found` on AWS lambda when trying to use `zip` command to zip a folder:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('touch /tmp/test.txt', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log(stdout);
  })
  exec('zip /tmp/test.zip /tmp/test.txt', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
           console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
           return;
         } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
  })
  exec('ls /tmp/', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log(stdout);
  })
```

Also when placing zip inside a bin folder, it is giving permission denied error. How to install zip module on AWS lambda?

Answer (score 2):

The `zip` package is not installed on the Amazon Linux servers that your Lambda function is running on. So have two options:

1) Provide the zip application binary as a part of your function package that you upload to Lambda. The zip application will need to be compiled on Amazon Linux or statically linked.

2) Use a Node.js library that doesn't have any dependencies on binary executables.

I've personally used option #2 and can recommend the excellent "yazl" library available here:

https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yazl

You'll end up doing something like this:

```
var yazl = require('yazl');

var zipfile = new yazl.ZipFile();
zipfile.addBuffer(fs.readFileSync('/tmp/file.txt'), "file.txt", {
  mtime: new Date(),
  mode: 0100664, // -rw-rw-r--
});
zipfile.outputStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.zip')).on("close", function() {
  console.log("done zipping files");
});
zipfile.end();
```

Comment: Method 1: Using binary from AMI instance `/usr/bin/zip` nothing happened, no error-no log nothing.
Method 2:  Using yazl  is giving out of memory issue for large file with video.

Comment: The memory will be an issue regardless of how you zip it. How much memory did you allocate to your function? Or are you talking about disk space? You only get 512MB of /tmp disk space.